# Qt WebView and cookie

Tags: qt, cookies, qml

As written here here https://forum.qt.io/post/578764 I can't use Qt WebEngine on Android, only WebView. Unfortunately `WebView QML Type` dont have `networkAccessManager` like `QWebView` from `QtWebKit`.
Please suggest how to use separate cookies database for different application users.

Look like I can manage cookies by file QtWebEngine\Default\Cookies in `standardLocations`. But this file is blocked while application is running. Maybe I can do something like this: stop QML QtWebView->operation with cookie file->start QtWebView?

Comment: QML WebView is using operating system's webview on Android and iOS. So, you should do whatever you do as if you are using operating system's webview. I'm not sure but I think that it is being handled by the operating system itself when it comes to different users.

Comment: Thanks. I mean about different user of my application, not system. And chace and cookies stored on the application standardLocations folder, not system.